# How to cluster data based on a subset of attributes (4 attributes)?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-mining, data-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a pandas DataFrame that holds the data for some objects, among which the position of some parts of the object (Left, Top, Right, Bottom).

For example:

```
ObjectID    Left, Right, Top, Bottom
1            0      0     0      0
2            20    15     5      5
3            3      2     0      0
```

How can I cluster the objects based on this 4 attributes? 
Is there a clustering algorithm/technique that you recommend me?

Answer (score 1):

Almost all clustering algorithms are *multivariate* and can be used here. So your question is too broad.

It may be worth looking at appropriate distance measures first.

Any recommendation would be sound to do, because we don't know how your data is *distributed*.

Answer (score 1):

depending upon the data type and final objective you can try k-means, k-modes or k-prototypes. if your data got a mix of categorical or continuous variables then you can try [partition around medoids](https://www.cs.umb.edu/cs738/pam1.pdf) algorithm. However, as stated earlier by another user, can you give more information about the type of data and its variance.